# @RequestMapping strange action - doesnt work redirection on return statement

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, redirect

I have very simple code in my Controller on Java:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
public class AdminController {
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printSettings() {

        return "admin";
    }
}
```

And i have some admin.jsp page, where  there are smth forms and fields, which i want to use. (there is sumbit button, which GET onClick to my controller)
All code are working (no mapping or another error). 
But, when i want to use func like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "inf", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String printSettings() {

            return "admin";
        }
    }
```

the return statement doesn't redirect me at '/admin'! It redirect at '/admin/inf'!
Why can be this strange behavior?

*in code at now a use `return "redirect:/admin";` to redirect to my jsp page. But a want that default redirection at string statement (such simple 'admin') are working!

Comment: `"admin"` isn't a redirect it is a forward to a view named 'admin'. Also a form should really do a POST not a GET (in general) and your form will go to `/admin/inf` due to the fact you aren't doing a redirect that remains in the address bar.

Comment: @M.Deinum, in my controller also there is POST form, but it work (doesn't work redirection) the same way. In documentation about SPRING says that if "string" return - it forward to it. But it doesn't work

Comment: A POST doesn't change the URL in the browser, whereas a GET does. It has nothing to do with the fact that a redirect isn't working it is how the view resolving in spring works. If you want to change the address/URL you have to do a redirect, else the URL will stay the same.

Comment: M.Denium is right. You have url "/admin" and you map it on view "admin" and another one "admin/inf" that is mapped on view "admin". You can map one url only on one view. So to perform what you want you should perfirm redirect. There is only option you have.